# loop curl could not resolve host

Tags: shell, curl

I've had working script, which suddenly doesn't works.
It contains something like this:

```
while read url;
do
    curl $url
done < links
```

links file:

```
http://duckduckgo.com
http://google.com
```

And I get couldn't resolve hostname error.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: duckduckgo.com
```

But, when the loop is removed, it works so it's not a network problem.

```
url="http://google.com"
curl $url
```

I've been looking into this whole day and I believe it is some stupidity but I wasn't able to figure it out. (quotes tried)

Comment: Your script works fine for me. Is there something else about the environment you're running under that might be missing?

Comment: I've no clue. Using Arch, recently did upgrade (pacman -Syyu)

Comment: Have you edited your `links` file since the last time this worked?  Is there any chance that you got invisible characters (like carriage returns) in there?  Try `read url < links; curl $url` (should do the first line only).

Comment: Yes, it is output from another script. Your example doen't works. I tried it in fresh install of xubuntu in virtual and got the same result.

Comment: The issue must be with your `links` file. I tried Scott's example and didn't have any issue when using my own, hand-crafted `links` file. Have your tried your script with a custom `links` file?

Comment: Sure, that was first thing I've tried